# How to display a dialog inside TimerTask's run() after calling Looper.prepare();?

Tags: android, timertask, android-timer

In activity's onCreate(), I arm a TimerTask that should display a dialog after 10 secs :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            Looper.prepare();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            
            Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "Dialog should be displayed...");
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("TEST")
                    .setMessage("This is a test")
                    .show();
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 10000);
}
```

When this activity is created, the Toast is displayed after 10 secs, but not the dialog.
Any idea why ?

I'm compiling using Android SDK 33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your code like this, your app will crash with the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method handleLifecycleEvent must be called on the main thread
```

The error you're seeing is because you're calling `Looper.prepare()` and creating a `AlertDialog` on a background thread. This is not allowed because `AlertDialog` must be created on the main thread.

To fix this, you can move the code that creates the `AlertDialog` inside the `runOnUiThread` method. This will ensure that the code is executed on the main thread. Here's how your code would look like with this change:

```
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Looper.prepare();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "Dialog should be displayed...");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .setTitle("TEST")
                                .setMessage("This is a test")
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 2000);
```